# Fried motherboard resistors, what to do?

Tags: resistors, motherboard

A motherboard failed under load recently, and here is the worry:

[image]
I am waiting for a new mainboard. What must i do about it? is it a very easy repair? I am mostly confused about identifying the resistors.

Comment: They are not resistors. They are non-polarized ceramic capacitors. Cannot be identified from a photo --can be 10nF, 100nF, or even 1uF. If you desolder and try to measure them, you cannot read a value.

Comment: I would focus on why it happened so that it would not happen to new motherboard. You may guess on value of capacitors, but I think there're other components which have failed.

Comment: Without a circuit diagram, it would be pretty hopeless trying to fix this. And probably not worth the hassle.

Comment: Hey thanks that's completely new to me, will have to find out the amazing chemistry of this kind of ceramic. there are other ones that are intact near it.

Comment: The processor was at 67 degrees for a day because sometimes the speedstep doesn't clock slower again, and there was a bit of fluff on the processor heatsink. I'd hope that wouldnt explode any kind of motherboard from ASUS. The board was probably a bit more than 2 years old. M5A78L-M/USB3

Comment: @comprehensible "others near those" won't help you – they don't necessarily have the same specs. If ceramic caps fail this catastrophically, your motherboard is severely broken, and repair is probably out of question, unless you can convince ASUS to give you schematics (they won't). Your exact motherboard costs 50€ nowadays. There's nothing economically sound to trying to repair it. Don't buy the same again, though; I've never seen this happen to ceramic capacitors, and it might really be a sign of bad design or misuse (electrical short somewhere, or broken power supply).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These a filtering caps on one of many of platform voltage rails. Capacitors blow up only due to overvoltage, or too much of ripples/ringing. Which means that some active components (power MOSFETs) are likely blown as well, causing this, and likely some other damage. These caps can be high-value (47uF-100uF) low-voltage (2.5V-4V) caps. Without proper schematics for this board it is not possible to repair it. And the schematics will be impossible to obtain. So throw the board away, or keep it for re-use its components for DIY projects.

Comment: Thanks alot i'll change the power supply too in case it is a ripple defect coming from the power supply, as marcus said too.

Answer (score 1):

The MOSFET just above is a 7 milliohm switch and there are 1RO resistors nearby, so these are very low ESR ceramic caps that should be able to handle many amps of peak currents, for some unknown reason developed too much ESR and self heating either from aging or defects or over-clocking.

If nothing else failed except overvoltage protection from ripple, you can try physical sizes that match from these [**parts**](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/capacitors/ceramic-capacitors/131083?k=&pkeyword=&pv5=8268&pv5=13&pv5=14308&pv5=5567&pv5=6520&pv5=9065&pv5=9006&pv5=15034&FV=fff40002%2Cfff8000b%2C340021%2C340022%2C340023%2C340024%2C340028%2C34016a%2C34016b%2C3401b2%2C3401b6%2C340333%2C340337%2C34056c%2C340637&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500), near 0.1uF with low ESL, low ESR.